# Unexpected token, in JSON at position 23

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Angular & HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
                <h1>{{ myWelcome }}</h1>
            </div>
            <p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                    $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost/dustbin/uxo_data/leaderboard.php"
                    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
                    }, function myError(response) {
                        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
                    });
                });
    </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Returns :

```
{"total":"4","phn":"1"},{"total":"1","phn":"2"}
```

Error :

`angular.min.js:107 SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 23`

Whats the error in above code, i am using angular in frontend and php in backend as rest-api

Comment: The returned data is not valid JSON. At least a surrounding `[]` would be missing.

Comment: in php use `json_encode` to return the array.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Can you add the relevant PHP code? At least you're using `json_encode()?` the wrong way.

Comment: Can you show the php snippet where and how you are using `json_encode()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate.

You need to wrap your data in square brackets `[]`.

```
[{"total":"4","phn":"1"},{"total":"1","phn":"2"}]
```

I suppose you're converting each object in JSON and sending them separated by comma on server side.

Instead, create an array in PHP which will consist of all your objects and then get json using build-in [`json_encode` function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$jsonstr = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a comment says you are missing a `[]`. If php sending json data then you should `json_encode()` it.

```
echo json_encode($object);
exit();
```